# Does the benefit outweigh the cost when an answer answers a tangential question?

Tags: discussion

Being that SO is for finding answers to questions, is it perfectly fine to answer a completely unrelated question when the error messages are trivially similar (i.e. generic enough that it helps some people searching for the term)?

For example, the question is about a plugin not being defined/not registered correctly and or multiple inclusion bugs:

```
$("#something").animate(...)
```

Produces an error like object `has no method animate`

However, the unrelated answer solves a very similar error "has no method" whose *cause* is way more obvious and completely unrelated to the actual question. Consider one such answer:

```
Answer: I forgot to include the $ sign when calling ("#something").hide()
```

So while this is helpful for a limited set of keyword searchers (gets a few upvotes because the question *seemingly* produces the same error), it is not helpful to the question at hand. What's the general opinion on this?

Comment: I think answers should be specific to the question asked. You can probably find a related question for which your answer is more directly relevant. Add a link to it in a comment.

Comment: I would tend to agree that answering with tangential question in mind adds noise to those trying to solve the problem at hand.